# Merge tags [aurelia] and [aurelia-framework]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

## Issue

The [aurelia-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aurelia-framework) tag currently has 183 questions tagged, *none* of which are [not also tagged with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aurelia-framework+-aurelia) [aurelia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aurelia). The tag itself has no description, and provides no context to the question that the [aurelia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aurelia) tag does not provide.

The description of [`aurelia-framework`](https://github.com/aurelia/framework) on GitHub is as follows:

> The aurelia framework brings together all the required core aurelia libraries into a ready-to-go application-building platform.

In my eyes, this is syntactically the same as the current description of the [aurelia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aurelia) tag.

### Suggestion

My suggestion is to make [aurelia-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aurelia-framework) a synonym of [aurelia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aurelia) and to remove the tag from the questions having it.

Comment: It seems better to keep the aurelia-framework tag; if you look at the github page, aurelia-framework is [a thing there too](https://github.com/aurelia) as there are several components housed under the Aurelia project.

Comment: @Gimby looking at the description of said project, it is not a seperate library housed under Aurelia, but it's a platform bringing together all of the components. So syntactically there is no difference with the Aurelia platform.